# How can I group multiple records as a single .csv string line?

Tags: postgresql, group-by, group-concatenation, google-bigquery, string-aggregation

I have a relation where a User has multiple dogs (as many as 15) but each dog is contained in a single row in the table, and they all have a userId in common.

```
For example, Table `dogs`:
|   User    |    Dog Name     |  Age
|   ABCD    |      Fido       |  7
|   ABCD    |      Gooofy     |  9
|   ABCD    |      Toto       |  4
|   ABCD    |      Roger      |  12
|   ABCD    |      Barkley    |  3
```

I would like to do something like `SELECT * FROM dogs GROUP BY User` where the result will output a csv of `ABCD`s dogs, as follows:

```
ABCD, Fido, 7, Goofy, 9, Toto, 4, Roger, 12, Barkley, 3
```

I'm using BigQuery but I think knowing how to do this in PostgreSQL may even be helpful. So maybe I can create some sort of view or something?

Comment: there are some aggregration function in big query https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31368235/bigquery-group-concat-and-order-by

Comment: I extensively revised my previous answer - you might want to take a look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Discussion:

To resolve this, I did the two things - the first is that I answered the question as asked and then I answer the question in what I think is more robust way.

This "better" way is not to store `age` as a field, because by definition, age is mutable - it increments every year, so you should do any calculations of `age` on the fly relative to the date upon which the `age` was calculated by comparing it to something which **is** immutable, i.e. the birth date/year.

### Part 1: Question as asked.

For the question as asked, see [this fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=3752545d400a8afd753f96e166f0c998) for PostgreSQL code and [this one](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.5&fiddle=22ee0b1135261746c80d885fa3bf66bf) for MySQL.

Create our table:

```
CREATE TABLE dog
(
  owner TEXT NOT NULL,
  name  TEXT NOT NULL,
  age   SMALLINT NOT NULL
);
```

Populate it:

```
INSERT INTO dog VALUES
('abc', 'fido', 4),
('abc', 'tim',  6),
('abc', 'max',  9),
('abc', 'fred', 1),
('xyz', 'joe',  4),
('xyz', 'jim',  2);
```

and then run this SQL:

```
SELECT 
  owner, 
  STRING_AGG(name || ' '  || age, ',' ORDER BY age) AS doggies
FROM dog
GROUP BY owner;
```

Result:

```
owner   doggies
abc     fred 1,fido 4,tim 6,max 9
xyz     jim 2,joe 4
```

It appears that Google's BigQuery system uses the [STRING_AGG](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/aggregate_functions#string_agg) syntax.

Both queries work on the oldest system that I could find to test on - i.e. PostgreSQL 9.5 and MySQL 5.5 - this should get you started!

### Part 2: Robust method.

Now, to answer the question in a more robust way. The dog  table now has an **immutable** attribute - the year of birth from which we can always calculate an age now and at any time into the future. Note `birth_year` (which never changes) and not `age`.

We create a second table:

```
CREATE TABLE dog_2
(
  owner      TEXT NOT NULL,
  name       TEXT NOT NULL,
  birth_year SMALLINT NOT NULL 

    CHECK (birth_year <= DATE_PART('YEAR', CURRENT_DATE) 
       AND birth_year >= DATE_PART('YEAR', CURRENT_DATE) - 30),

    -- Or the same thing written according to the SQL Standard.

    CHECK (birth_year <= EXTRACT('YEAR' FROM CURRENT_DATE) 
       AND birth_year >= EXTRACT('YEAR' FROM CURRENT_DATE) - 30)
);
```

The 30 number is not plucked from the air - I got it from [here](https://www.guinnessworldrecords.com/world-records/oldest-dog#:%7E:text=The%20greatest%20reliable%20age%20recorded,sleep%20on%2014%20November%201939.)! Then:

```
INSERT INTO dog_2 VALUES
('abc', 'fido', 2017),
('abc', 'tim',  2015),
('abc', 'max',  2012),
('abc', 'fred', 2020),
('xyz', 'joe',  2017),
('xyz', 'jim',  2019);
```

and then we run:

```
SELECT 
  owner,
  STRING_AGG
  (
    name || 
    ' '  || 
    (EXTRACT('YEAR' FROM CURRENT_DATE) - birth_year)::TEXT, ', ' ORDER BY birth_year DESC
  )
FROM
  dog_2
GROUP BY owner;
```

Result:

```
owner   string_agg
abc     fred 1, fido 4, tim 6, max 9
xyz     jim 2, joe 4
```

- For PostgreSQL, see the same 9.5 fiddle - works for both!
- For MySQL, there is a problem (*quelle suprise*)! It won't let [non-deterministic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/user-defined-functions/deterministic-and-nondeterministic-functions?view=sql-server-ver15) function in `CHECK` constraints - although PostgreSQL does support some of them. To my mind, `CURRENT_DATE()` **is** deterministic, because for a given set of circumstances, it will **always** return the same value - unlike `RAND()` or `UUID()`... anyway, YMMV.

  However, MySQL has only had `CHECK` constraints since it's only [had them since 2019](https://mysqlserverteam.com/mysql-8-0-16-introducing-check-constraint) (a mere 27 years after the SQL Standard mandated them!!!), maybe they've some catching up to do! This means that the fiddle is also for version 8 - you can find it [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5d51fbd20bd92e22cae9518bc58fb246).

So, the best I could do for MySQL was the following:

```
CREATE TABLE dog_2
(
  owner      TEXT NOT NULL,
  name       TEXT NOT NULL,
  birth_year SMALLINT NOT NULL 

  CHECK (birth_year < 2021 AND birth_year > 1990)

--
-- Won't work!
--
--  CHECK (birth_year <= YEAR(CURRENT_DATE()) AND birth_year >= YEAR(CURRENT_DATE()) - 30)
--
);
```

Note that this requires the `CHECK` constraint in the table definition to be updated every year - which is perhaps a bit better than having to update every record? You could perhaps even programme an [`EVENT`](https://www.surekhatech.com/blog/mysql-event-scheduler#:%7E:text=What%20is%20MySql%20Event%20Scheduler,multiple%20times%20at%20specified%20intervals.)?

And populate it as above, and then run the following SQL:

```
SELECT 
  owner, 
  GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT
                 (
                   name, 
                   ' ',  
                   YEAR(CURRENT_DATE()) - birth_year
                 ) 
                 ORDER BY birth_year 
                 SEPARATOR ', '
              ) AS doggies
FROM dog_2
GROUP BY owner;
```

Result:

```
owner   doggies
abc     max 9, tim 6, fido 4, fred 1
xyz     joe 4, jim 2
```

As mentioned above, the BigQuery implementation appears to use the PostgreSQL implementation, so you might be in luck!